# Fancybox iframe pops up but url is not loading

Tags: jquery, fancybox

It says in cosole => Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'showIframe' of undefined at HTMLIFrameElement.onload at line 1 but there are no errors 
.....

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../src/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.2.6.css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="../fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.2.6.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">


  jQuery(document).ready(function($){
           $("a.iframe").fancybox({
            'zoomSpeedIn'       :   500,
            'zoomSpeedOut'      :   450,
            'frameHeight'       :   400,
            'frameWidth'        :   525,
            'overlayShow'       :   true,
            'overlayOpacity'    :   0.6,
            'type'              :  'iframe'
        });
    });
</script> 
<a href="https://example.com" class="iframe">Edit</a>
```

...

Comment: Is there any reason why you are not using v3? Also, your snippet works fine - http://jsfiddle.net/1rarb9cu/ - maybe there is something with your iframed page?

Comment: Working with old sites so.
What is the reason of the error arrising  **Cannot read property 'showIframe'**

Comment: No idea, because your code works fine and you did not provide a link to live page demonstrating this issue. It is also not clear from your description if this message comes from iframed page or from the main page.

Comment: Also, I do not see `showIframe` method at source code of fancyBox, so it must come from somewhere else.

Comment: its solved
I had added extra jquery.min.js in my footer.

Answer (score 0):

its solved I had added extra jquery.min.js in my footer.